# Replace string before parentheses

Tags: r, regex, string

I am trying to replace numbers before parentheses:

```
string <- "1234556 (789)"
    
sub("*.\\(*.", "foo", string)  

[1] "foo34556 (789)"
```

I am looking for this result:

```
 result <- "foo (789)"
```

Comment: Try `sub(".*\\(", "foo (", string)`The `*.` should be `.*`

Comment: `sub(".*(\\()" , "foo \\1" , string)` .

Answer (score 0):

This should be the correct regex

```
sub("[0-9]+", "foo", string)
```

> "foo (789)"

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
> sub("^[^( ]+", "foo", string)
[1] "foo (789)"
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace numbers before the parenthesis, you can match 1 or more digits (which should be replaced), and capture the optional spaces including from an opening till closing parenthesis in group 1.

In the replacement use `foo` followed by the group 1 value.

```
string <- "1234556 (789)"
sub("\\d+(\\s*\\([^()]*\\))", "foo\\1", string)
```

Output

```
[1] "foo (789)"
```

See an [R demo](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7ikKDMvXcFGV0HJ0MjYxNTUTEHD3MJSU4mruDRJQykmJkVbIyamWCsmRiM6TkMzFsjQ1FTSUVBKy8@PiTEEsiAmaHL9/w8A) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HulfB1/1) for the match and group value.